# How to access Kotlin Lambda functions from databinding in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, lambda, data-binding, invoke

I've the following Wrapper class

```
class ApiWrapper<I, O>(
    val response: LiveData<Resource<O>>,
    val call: (I?) -> Unit
) {
    val loading = map(response) { it.status == RequestState.LOADING }
}
```

And I've the following databinding expression

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/signInBtn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="@{!vm.login.loading}"
            android:onClick="@{()->vm.login.call(vm.auth)}"
            android:text="@string/sign_in"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
```

`login` variable in ViewModel holds a wrapper object from repository (Ignoring the details for brevity).

Now when I run,  I get this exception

> [databinding] {"msg":"cannot find method call(com.fishlee.auth.Auth) in class com.fishlee.etc.api.ApiWrapper\u003ccom.fishlee.auth.Auth,com.fishlee.auth.AuthState\u003e"

Why can't databinding find the method in the wrapper class?

I've a work around, Which is to create a method inside the `ViewModel` and call wrapper's call method from there. But I really would love to call it directly from databinding expression that was the whole point of ApiWrapper class, How do I achieve this with databinding using Kotlin? Any help would be highly appreciated!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the data binding library you're still strongly bound to the *Java* world. There you can only call to methods. But your *Kotlin* lambda is technically an interface, so just call the `invoke` method directly. It's not as nice as making a call on the object, but better than defining a different method thereafter.

```
android:onClick="@{()->vm.login.call.invoke(vm.auth)}"
```

Comment: Given it's a field, maybe you need to use getter syntax. (unless you annotate it with `@JvmField`) So, `android:onClick="@{()->vm.login.getCall.invoke(vm.auth)}"`

Comment: @XavierRubioJansana As far as I know, data binding has the property mapping implemented as well.

Comment: You're right, I think databinding code generator takes care of identifying whether field or getter/setter syntax must be used in the generated code.

Comment: FWIW, I filed [a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129784890) to allow us to just use the `()` syntax, bypassing `invoke()`.